# NSString format

Tags: iphone, objective-c, nsstring

I have a `NSString` I am getting from an array. There are multiple string objects in the array. I want to change the format of the string I get from array and display that new formatted string on `UILabel`. Let me give an example:

String in array: **539000**
String I want to display: **5.390.00**

Now the problem is that the string I get from array may be **539000**, **14200** or **9050**. So the string I want to get are: **5.390.00**, **142.00**, **90.50**.

The correct format is to place a `**.**` before last two digits, again place a `**.**` before 3 digits from first `**.**`.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

**Try below code it will help**

**Objective-C**

```
NSNumberFormatter *formatter = [[NSNumberFormatter alloc] init]; 
[formatter setGroupingSeparator:@"."];
[formatter setGroupingSize:2];
[formatter setUsesGroupingSeparator:YES];
[formatter setSecondaryGroupingSize:3];

NSString *input = @"539000";
NSString *output = [formatter stringFromNumber:[NSNumber numberWithDouble:[input doubleValue]]];
NSLog(@"output :: %@",output);// output :: 5.390.00
```

**Swift3**

```
let formatter = NumberFormatter()
    formatter.groupingSeparator = "."
    formatter.groupingSize = 2
    formatter.usesGroupingSeparator = true
    formatter.secondaryGroupingSize = 3

    let input = 539000
    let output = formatter.string(from: NSNumber.init(value: input))
    print("output :: \(output!)")// output :: 5.390.00
```